# How to sort form fields in customer address book - Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, address

How can I sort the form fields in the customer address book?
For example: I need the zip code above the city.

I have already sorted the form fields in the checkout_index_index.xml for the checkout as in [this post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/140195/magento-2-how-to-change-the-sortorder-of-the-street-address-fields-on-the-ship). That works great.

Does anyone have an idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below custom module and modify it according to your requirement.

**app/code/Anshu/CustomerAddress/registration.php**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Anshu_CustomerAddress',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/Anshu/CustomerAddress/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Anshu_CustomerAddress" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/Anshu/CustomerAddress/view/frontend/layout/customer_address_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_address_edit" template="Anshu_CustomerAddress::address/edit.phtml" />
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/Anshu/CustomerAddress/view/frontend/templates/address/edit.phtml**

```
<?php

/** @var \Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Edit $block */
/** @var \Magento\Customer\ViewModel\Address $viewModel */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Helper\SecureHtmlRenderer $secureRenderer */
$viewModel = $block->getViewModel();
?>
<?php $_company = $block->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Company::class) ?>
<?php $_telephone = $block->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Telephone::class) ?>
<?php $_fax = $block->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Fax::class) ?>
<?php $_country_id = $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('country_id'); ?>
<?php $_street = $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('street'); ?>
<?php $_city = $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('city'); ?>
<?php $_region = $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('region'); ?>
<?php $_selectRegion = 'Please select a region, state or province.'; ?>
<?php $_displayAll = $block->getConfig('general/region/display_all'); ?>

<?php $_vatidValidationClass = $viewModel->addressGetAttributeValidationClass('vat_id'); ?>
<?php $_cityValidationClass = $viewModel->addressGetAttributeValidationClass('city'); ?>
<?php $_postcodeValidationClass_value = $viewModel->addressGetAttributeValidationClass('postcode'); ?>
<?php $_postcodeValidationClass = $_postcodeValidationClass_value; ?>
<?php $_streetValidationClass = $viewModel->addressGetAttributeValidationClass('street'); ?>
<?php $_streetValidationClassNotRequired = trim(str_replace('required-entry', '', $_streetValidationClass)); ?>
<?php $_regionValidationClass = $viewModel->addressGetAttributeValidationClass('region'); ?>
<form class="form-address-edit"
      action="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($block->getSaveUrl()) ?>"
      method="post"
      id="form-validate"
      enctype="multipart/form-data"
      data-hasrequired="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr(__('* Required Fields')) ?>">
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <legend class="legend"><span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Contact Information')) ?></span></legend><br>
        <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($block->getSuccessUrl()) ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($block->getErrorUrl()) ?>">
        <?= $block->getNameBlockHtml() ?>

        <?php if ($_company->isEnabled()): ?>
            <?= $_company->setCompany($block->getAddress()->getCompany())->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php if ($_telephone->isEnabled()): ?>
            <?= $_telephone->setTelephone($block->getAddress()->getTelephone())->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php if ($_fax->isEnabled()): ?>
            <?= $_fax->setFax($block->getAddress()->getFax())->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif ?>

    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <legend class="legend"><span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Address')) ?></span></legend><br>
        <div class="field street required">
            <label for="street_1" class="label"><span><?= /* @noEscape */ $_street ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <div class="field primary">
                    <label for="street_1" class="label">
                        <span>
                            <?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Street Address: Line %1', 1)) ?>
                        </span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <input type="text"
                       name="street[]"
                       value="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getStreetLine(1)) ?>"
                       title="<?= /* @noEscape */ $_street ?>"
                       id="street_1"
                       class="input-text <?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($_streetValidationClass) ?>"/>
                <div class="nested">
                    <?php for ($_i = 1, $_n = $viewModel->addressGetStreetLines(); $_i < $_n; $_i++): ?>
                        <div class="field additional">
                            <label class="label" for="street_<?= /* @noEscape */ $_i + 1 ?>">
                                <span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Street Address: Line %1', $_i + 1)) ?></span>
                            </label>
                            <div class="control">
                                <input type="text" name="street[]"
                                       value="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getStreetLine($_i + 1)) ?>"
                                       title="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Street Address %1', $_i + 1)) ?>"
                                       id="street_<?= /* @noEscape */ $_i + 1 ?>"
                                       class="input-text
                                        <?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($_streetValidationClassNotRequired) ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endfor; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php if ($viewModel->addressIsVatAttributeVisible()): ?>
            <div class="field taxvat">
                <label class="label" for="vat_id">
                    <span><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('vat_id') ?></span>
                </label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text"
                           name="vat_id"
                           value="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAddress()->getVatId()) ?>"
                           title="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('vat_id') ?>"
                           class="input-text <?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($_vatidValidationClass) ?>"
                           id="vat_id">
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="field country required">
            <label class="label" for="country">
                <span><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('country_id') ?></span>
            </label>
            <div class="control">
                <?= $block->getCountryHtmlSelect() ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field region required">
            <label class="label" for="region_id">
                <span><?= /* @noEscape */ $_region ?></span>
            </label>
            <div class="control">
                <select id="region_id" name="region_id"
                        title="<?= /* @noEscape */ $_region ?>"
                        class="validate-select region_id"
                    <?= /* @noEscape */ !$_displayAll ? ' disabled="disabled"' : '' ?>>
                    <option value=""><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__($_selectRegion)) ?></option>
                </select>
                <input type="text"
                       id="region"
                       name="region"
                       value="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getRegion()) ?>"
                       title="<?= /* @noEscape */ $_region ?>"
                       class="input-text validate-not-number-first
                        <?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($_regionValidationClass) ?>"
                    <?= !$_displayAll ? ' disabled="disabled"' : '' ?>/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field zip required">
            <label class="label" for="zip">
                <span><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('postcode') ?></span>
            </label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text"
                       name="postcode"
                       value="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAddress()->getPostcode()) ?>"
                       title="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('postcode') ?>"
                       id="zip"
                       class="input-text validate-zip-international
                        <?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($_postcodeValidationClass) ?>">
                <div role="alert" class="message warning">
                    <span></span>
                </div>
                <?= /* @noEscape */ $secureRenderer->renderStyleAsTag("display: none;", 'div.message.warning') ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field city required">
            <label class="label" for="city">
                <span><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('city') ?></span>
            </label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text"
                       name="city"
                       value="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAddress()->getCity()) ?>"
                       title="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr(__('City')) ?>"
                       class="input-text <?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($_cityValidationClass) ?>"
                       id="city">
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php if ($block->isDefaultBilling()): ?>
            <div class="message info">
                <span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__("It's a default billing address.")) ?></span>
            </div>
        <?php elseif ($block->canSetAsDefaultBilling()): ?>
            <div class="field choice set billing">
                <input type="checkbox" id="primary_billing" name="default_billing" value="1" class="checkbox">
                <label class="label" for="primary_billing">
                    <span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Use as my default billing address')) ?></span>
                </label>
            </div>
        <?php else: ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="default_billing" value="1" />
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($block->isDefaultShipping()): ?>
            <div class="message info">
                <span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__("It's a default shipping address.")) ?></span>
            </div>
        <?php elseif ($block->canSetAsDefaultShipping()): ?>
            <div class="field choice set shipping">
                <input type="checkbox" id="primary_shipping" name="default_shipping" value="1" class="checkbox">
                <label class="label" for="primary_shipping">
                    <span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Use as my default shipping address')) ?></span>
                </label>
            </div>
        <?php else: ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="default_shipping" value="1">
        <?php endif; ?>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <button type="submit"
                    class="action save primary"
                    data-action="save-address"
                    title="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Save Address')) ?>">
                <span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Save Address')) ?></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="secondary">
            <a class="action back" href="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($block->getBackUrl()) ?>">
                <span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Go back')) ?></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#form-validate": {
            "addressValidation": {
                "postCodes": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getPostCodeConfig()->getSerializedPostCodes() ?>
            }
        },
        "#country": {
            "regionUpdater": {
                "optionalRegionAllowed": <?= /* @noEscape */ $_displayAll ? 'true' : 'false' ?>,
                "regionListId": "#region_id",
                "regionInputId": "#region",
                "postcodeId": "#zip",
                "form": "#form-validate",
                "regionJson": <?= /* @noEscape */ $viewModel->dataGetRegionJson() ?>,
                "defaultRegion": "<?= (int) $block->getRegionId() ?>",
                "countriesWithOptionalZip": <?= /* @noEscape */ $viewModel->dataGetCountriesWithOptionalZip(true) ?>
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here, In my custom module Anshu_CustomerAddress, I have created the layout file and overridden the phtml file to make the desired changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/address/edit.phtml` as follow,

**app/code/Vendor/Module/registration.xml**

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

ComponentRegistrar::register(
    ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module', __DIR__);
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">                 
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
    </sequence>

    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/customer_address_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_address_edit" >
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">
                    Vendor_Module::address/edit.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/address/edit.phtml**

copy the content of `vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/address/edit.phtml` and change the div block order.

after end of  `<div class="field zip required">` then placed to the

```
  <div class="field city required">
            <label class="label" for="city"><span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('City')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $this->helper(\Magento\Framework\EscapeHelper::class)->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAddress()->getCity()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->helper(\Magento\Framework\EscapeHelper::class)->escapeHtmlAttr(__('City')) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper(\Magento\Framework\EscapeHelper::class)->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper(\Magento\Customer\Helper\Address::class)->getAttributeValidationClass('city')) ?>" id="city">
            </div>
        </div>
```

then after,

```
 php bin/magento setup:di:compile
 php bin/magento setup:upgrade
 php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this answer helpful for you !!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a custom theme, you can simply copy:

*vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/address/edit.phtml*

to:

*app/design/frontend/[NameSpace]/[ThemeName]/Magento_Customer/templates/address/edit.phtml*

and edit as needed.